# What is the shortcut for toggling Column Selection Mode in RubyMine for OS X?

Tags: macos, rubymine

The edit menu shows that the shortcut for Column Selection Mode is **Shift+Command+*** when using the **default keymap**.  **Shift+Command+*** does not toggle Column Selection Mode.

Am I incorrect in thinking **Shift+Command+*** is the same as **Shift+Command+8** (numeric 8  key) the same thing?

Comment: also applies to IntelliJ and presumably other jetbrains products

Answer (score 3):

Open `Preferences` | `Keymap` and add the keyboard shortcut for this action to see what is the actual key code specific to your keyboard layout:

[image]

Comment: In the menu it shows something like `Shift+Command+Keyboard(?)+*`, so maybe that means on the numeric keypad? Which I don't have. But I used this to set the keyboard shortcut to `Shift+Command+8`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's numeric keyboard. For mac numeric keyboard available by Fn key. For my Macbook pro combination **Shift+Command+Keyboard(?)+*** means **Shift+Command+Fn+P**

Answer (score 0):

Toggling column selection mode doesn't work for me on Mac with the default mapping. I re-mapped it to alt+cmd+8 and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`Shift+Control+Command+8` works in IntelliJ on built-in keyboard on MacBook Pro (Mid 2015, OSX 10.11 El Capitan)

Thanks to https://guruv.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/ae-macbook-pro-shortcuts-for-the-numpad-deprived/